# Another way to send picture to Gmail

Tags: html, image, email, gmail, mime

Gmail hides pictures by default if they are from another website.
How softwares like Outlook send the signature pictures to Gmail without becoming hidden?

Comment: That's incorrect. [Gmail shows images by default](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2013/12/images-now-showing.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the person is in your Gmail contacts then the images appear as normal. Make sure people are adding your address to their contacts and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

As @rds pointed out earlier, Gmail now defaults to display external images without asking first. However, even with asking enabled, there is a way to get the image displayed.

Gmail and most email clients like Outlook will display any image *embedded* in the email and *may* prompt for downloading images that are external to the email.

Embedded images are attached to the email in a very similar manner to regular attachments, except that:

- their MIME `Content-Disposition` header is `inline`, instead of `attachment`.
- they feature a `Content-ID` header, which allows referencing the inlined content from the HTML part of the email. For instance, if the `Content-ID` header is "myimage", you may reference it as `<img src="cid:myimage" />.`

External images are plain vanilla references to external resources, e.g. `<img src="http://example.org/images/myimage.png" />`.

Email clients do this as a security/privacy measure. Downloading external images allow email senders to track email openings by tracking image downloads on their own infrastructure, e.g. by using a custom URL for each recipient, e.g. `<img src="http://example.org/track.png?recipient-id=493275735" />`.